# Мониторинг MPLS сети

Tags: сеть, mikrotik, cisco, snmp

Вопрос в том, что есть сеть в которой используются устройства Cisco, HPE, Mikrotik с транспортом MPLS L3VPN (OSPF, LDP, MBGP). Не могу понять как мониторить пути LSP, а также клиентские VPN (чтобы понимать если отвалиться линк и перестроиться LSP каким путем оно будет идти, а также хотелось бы видеть куда ходит клиентский трафик). В роли NMS используется сервер мониторинга PRTG. Пытался мониторить через SNMPv2(по RFC 4221, картинка древа прилагается): скачал нужные MIB'и для мониторинга MPLS (Cisco, HPE, для Mikrotik MPLS MIB'ов вообще нету) засунул их в PRTG, добавил сенсоры. Показуют они неадекватно, и их очень много, наглядной информации они не дают. Зашел в тупик, не представляю как сделать наглядный мониторинг MPLS-сети.